# Tree traversal with Haskell

Tags: haskell, recursion, tree

Hi all this is my first question here, I'm very new to Haskell and I need to do a Haskell function which takes a Tree and returns a list of the elements in its node in a preorder traversal but I can't get it to work.

My Tree definition is the following:

```
data Tree a = Node a [Tree a] deriving Show
```

and the preorder function is:

```
preorderTree :: Tree a -> [a]
preorderTree Empty = []
preorderTree (Node a l r) = a : (preorderTree l) ++ (preorderTree r)
```

In advance thank you very much for your help :)

Comment: Well, you've written `Node` to take only two arguments, but pattern-matched on three.

Comment: You have the data definition of a rose tree but a function that seems to expect a binary tree. If you want `preorderTree` to work for your `Tree` data type, take a look at `concatMap`.

Comment: This actually isn't your first question since you didn't actually ask anything. You also haven't posted any error messages.  Given that the traversal and the data declaration don't match, there are two possible fixes.  Which fix is correct is unclear, so I voted to close.  Feel free to edit the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Haskell, **type** is a set of **value**s. So we have both type constructor and value constructor.

So writing a haskell function. We need properly define the **type** (`Tree`). Deal every **value**(`Empty`, `Node ...`) in the corresponding **type**.

`Tree a` is a **type**. Its value is either `Empty` or a bunch of children. Thus we have

```
data Tree a = Empty
            | Node a [Tree a]
```

So when we write a function like `preorderTree :: Tree a -> [a]`. We are dealing with **type** `Tree a`, so we have to deal with value `Empty` and `Node a [Tree a]`. So we have

```
preorderTree :: Tree a -> [a]
preorderTree Empty = []
preorderTree (Node a children) = a : concatMap preorderTree children
```

This is a rose tree, if you just want a binary tree, we need to change the value constructor of type `Tree a`, because `[Tree a]` is just too much for a binary tree. So we have

```
data Tree a = Empty
            | Node a (Tree a) (Tree a)

preorderTree :: Tree a -> [a]
preorderTree Empty = []
preorderTree (Node a left right) = a : preorderTree left ++ preorderTree right
```

---

1. https://wiki.haskell.org/Constructor

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, this really help me and also I'm starting to really like Haskell :)